# Sourcing an alternative strain relief adapter

Tags: components, appliances

I'm doing a simple modification of my old Sony sound system. It came with no earth wire and I wish to replace the cable and connect the earth to the metal chassis of the stereo. My issue is that the cable strain relief gland is designed for a flatter cable.

I could try grinding out the shape of the teeth of this part but I don't want to mess it up or find I need to back out/revert and have no options. I'm wondering if I can source an alternative part to replace the one shown.

It inserts into a sheet metal hole that is approximately rectangular, but with rounded corners and a notch removed at the top. The part is 11x15.5 mm where it inserts.

[image: cable strain gland]

I haven't found a part quite like this on the internet yet (I'm in the UK by the way). I may have been searching using the wrong name though. I've tried "cable strain relief" "strain relief gland".

Any advice appreciated!

Comment: Try *strain relief bushing*. *Heyco* makes many versions, I have only used the round ones.

Answer (score 2):

This is a "strain relief bushing", or "strain relief grommet".

I have seen them for round cable, but these needed a round hole (preferrably a round hole with flats).